# Send a value from listfragment to another fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, parameter-passing

I would like to send a value from ListFragment to another Fragment.....

Here is my code:
MainFragments.java:

```
public class MainFragments extends ListFragment {
protected List<ParseObject> Ads;
Button btn_LogOut;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container, false);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Ads");
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {


        @Override
public void done(List<ParseObject> Adsobjects, ParseException e) {
    if(e==null){
        Ads=Adsobjects;
        AdsAdapter adapter =new AdsAdapter(getListView().getContext(),Ads);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }else{

    }

}
});



    btn_LogOut=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonlogout);

    btn_LogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseUser.logOut();
            updateDetail();

        }
    });
    return rootView;


  }

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ParseObject AdsObject= Ads.get(position);
    String objectId = AdsObject.getObjectId();

    Toast.makeText(getContext(),objectId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("KEY_DETAIL", objectId);
    MydetailsAdsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, MydetailsAdsFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

public void updateDetail() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

MydetailsAdsFragment:

```
public class MydetailsAdsFragment extends Fragment {
TextView textDetail;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details_ads, container, false);
    textDetail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTxt_det_Titleads);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if(bundle != null) {
        String detail = bundle.getString("KEY_DETAIL", "no argument pass");
        textDetail.setText(detail);
    }

    return rootView;

}
public void updateDetail(String detail) {
    textDetail.setText(detail);
}

}
```

I would like to know how can I solve this?

Your help will be appreciated!

Regards,
Marwan

Comment: Have you seen the official Android docs: [Communicating with other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

If the Fragments are inflated by the same Activity, you should define interfaces in the Fragments that the Activity will implement and pass data between them through the Activity. The link that PPartisan has provided has an example of this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html